# Win7 registry problem

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I have an application that access registry for finding the path where is installed Expression Web in order to open some .html files with Expression Web.

In Windows XP works ok. In Win7 not. What should I do in this case?

I'm using C# for accessing registry keys.

Comment: How does it "not work"? Is the registry key not found? Is it found but wrong? Could we see the code that accesses the registry?

Comment: Are you on 64-bit or 32-bit Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Win7 vs XP is probably a red herring.
Start by finding the key in regedit and making sure that you can invoke Expression Web from the commandline using the value of the registry keys.
Attempt at psychic debugging: if your Win7 OS is 64-bit and XP isn't, you may have forgotten the 32-bit designator after Program files.

If those things don't work, we'll probably need more information.

Comment: I didnt do the -1, but the point of the -1 is presumably that [UAC] registry virtualisation is very much in play as until the question rules it out

Answer (score 0):

You need administrative privileges to access Local Machine (HKLM) in 7 (and vista). Look here, the answer to this question might help you:
[Requested registry access is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562350/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed)

Comment: No you don't. You only need administrator access to *write* to HKLM but everyone can read from it. Although the problem in this case might be that the code actually requests write access, in addition to read.