# C# Create Values in Registry Local Machine

Tags: c#, registry

The following code is not working for me:

```
public bool createRegistry()
{
    if (!registryExists())
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\xelo\\");

        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\xelo").SetValue("hostname", (string)hostname, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);


        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return updateRegistry();
    }
}
```

Exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException | "Cannot write to the registry
>   key"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Non-admin and unelevated admin users don't have rights to modify the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key.  Run the program 'as administrator'.

Comment: Try passing true to the 2nd parameter of the OpenSubKey call or using the return value of CreateSubKey.  
   
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey.aspx  
  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Kyle, you have to do OpenSubKey("KeyName", true) Where the true means writable :D, Edit your answer to include that

Comment: @segfault, Did that same problem, need write access on the function

Comment: The answer, as it stands in incomplete/wrong. The comments are right.

Answer (score 12):

Below code to create key in the registry.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Names");
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");
key.Close();
```

Comment: I received a `Additional information: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Names' is denied.` error when running the snippet. Please advise.

Comment: Run application as administrator and it should work.

Comment: What if i wana use numbers? do i do `key.SetValue("Name", "1");`?

Comment: @Nullify you try like this shown in the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 10):

Even when admin I don't think you can create new keys off LocalMachine. Make sure that you do

```
Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\YourCompanyName\SomeNewKey");
```

and not

```
Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SomeNewKey");
```

Comment: Exactly, running this snippet above in VS or by going to `/bin/Debug/App.exe` and running that as Admin resulted in the below error: 

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourCompanyName\SomeNewKey' is denied.`

Comment: @Cole: You may want to post a new question with details specific to your problem. This method for writing to Registry is tried and true and I have been using it in commercial software for years. If you post your code we can help you figure out why you get this exception. My typical pattern is: `RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true); if (rk == null) { rk = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(path);} if(rk!=null){ .. do stuff .. rk.Close(); }`

Comment: `string path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers";
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true);`

which throws

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Requested registry access is not allowed.`

Comment: Dude, if you want help post a new question. I did try this path and it works fine for me. You need to post a new question with details specific to your problem (what OS, what architecture: 32-bit vs 64-bit). You possibly are running into probs with UAC / elevation or permissions. Also, try a search on that specific exception, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562350/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

Well you've got your answer already - I'm guessing you're running on Vista or Windows 7 (or Server 2008) and the process/user running the app doesn't have rights/permission to modify the registry.

So its not a code problem as such but a systems admin one. Build the app and run as administrator and see if that works.

Comment: I can confirm that updating HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE with admin rights  programmatically as suggested in the above code snippets and the accepted answer does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Set the Premission Check bit to true...

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\xelo\\", true);
```

:)

Comment: Registry.LocalMachine doesn't contain any overload method which allow [CreateSubKey(String,Bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: OpenSubkey() uses the boolean second arg to open the key writable. What you want is this: `.CreateSubKey(r,RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)`