# C# add key to registry to LocalMachine fails

Tags: c#, registry, 64-bit, administrator, wow64

I'm trying to add a key to `LocalMachine` in registry. I'm using this code:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true);
    RegistryKey newkey = key.CreateSubKey("1asdasds", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
    newkey.SetValue("ads", "ddsds");
    newkey.Close();
```

I DO run it on Administrator account. I event run it with 'run as administrator", but nothing is added to registry :(.
When I change the `LocalMachine` to `CurrentUser`, actually it is added to `CurrentUser` key. But how to force it to be added to LocalMachine?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723413/c-sharp-create-values-in-registry-local-machine/7208513#7208513

Comment: Strange, I've just tested your code as it is, the key was added to the registry just fine, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE, as expected. Windows 7 machine here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it. Actually it was added, but with my x64 system I couldn't see it in simple C:\Windows\regedit.exe. Go to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe to see it in x64