# Cannot write to Registry Key, getting UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exception, registry

I have a windows service that attempt to write to a registry key in LOCAL_MACHINE

The key is created as part of a windows installer package the controls the windows service and a stand alone control window.

The control window can read and write the registry key fine, however I cannot write to the registry key even when I give full permissions to LOCAL SERVICE.

This is the code that throws the exception:

```
private void updateLocalRegistryVersion(Double newVersion)
{
    RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
    RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(@"Software\CompanyName\Monitoring\Values");

    sk.SetValue("scriptversion", newVersion.ToString());
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(string)` does not open the key for writing. Try using the `OpenSubKey(string, bool)` overload to specify that you want the key to be writable.