# Can't write to 64-bit registry using .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, registry

I want to write to this registry

```
SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run
```

I tried this:

```
RegistryKey registryKey64 = RegistryKey
    .OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
    .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");

registryKey64.SetValue("CTIPopupForIPPhone", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

and I got this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot write to the registry key.

though I am running my Visual Studio as an administrator.

#### Update

During the development, I also tried

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser
    .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
```

but I got error that the entry doesn't exist though it **is** there, but I thought that because the `RegistryKey` is for Windows 32-bit not 64-bit.

Comment: can you access this registry through registry editor ? And can u update it from registry editor ?

Comment: @Kapoor and do u normally ask you clients to do that?

Comment: Obviously not !! it was  a  check if u have the permissions to access the registry at first place  ... then one can isolate if its a software issue or a permission (registry issue )

Comment: Please use proper capitalization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot write to the registry key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202752/cannot-write-to-the-registry-key) (or possibly [Cannot write to Registry Key, getting UnauthorizedAccessException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463706/cannot-write-to-registry-key-getting-unauthorizedaccessexception)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me,

```
RegistryKey registryKey64 = RegistryKey
    .OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
    .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
```

The new variable `true` is to both read and write over registry entry to allow both of them.

Comment: It's worth adding a link to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx) which explains what the additional Boolean parameter does - "If writable is true, the key will be opened for reading and writing, otherwise, the key will be opened as read-only".

Comment: @DanielKelley exactly, the parameter is for write and read together it