# UnauthorizedAccessException even with FullControl for 'Everyone'

Tags: c#, io, file-permissions

I get this error when trying to delete a file on `AppData\...`

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '...AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\4peif3cq.default\extensions\om.brunolm@gmail.com.xpi' is denied.

```
if (File.Exists(extFile))
{
    File.Delete(extFile);
}
```

I've tried to add `FullControl` permission to `Everyone`, but the same error happens. The file is not `readonly`.

Why can't I delete this file with C# code? How can I delete it?

Comment: Probably It has sth to do with trust level of your assembly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you also have full control on the folder that contains a file? Can you view effective permissions under advanced security settings? Or possibly someone else is using that file, that will deny access no matter what.

Comment: Actually Firefox was still open using the file. So it was denying access no matter what :P. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the same with elevated privileges:

- First, run your app under admin (Run as administrator in file's context menu).
- If that helped, add this to your App.manifest:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
     <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
           <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
              <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
           </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
     </trustInfo>
  </asmv1:assembly>
  ```

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562350/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed)