# Read-only access to registry raises security exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, registry

I am working with an application once written for Windows XP, making it work for Windows Vista and later. Formerly there was a lot of read and write accesses to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in registry. I've rewritten this so that only the installer writes to `HKEY_LOCAL_MAHINE` (with elevated privileges) and the application accesses these settings with read-only access. The application is written in C# and C++ and compiled for 32 bit.

Everything is working fine on my development computer running Windows 7. I have also tested the installer and application an a clean (virtual) Windows 7, both as a local administrator and a normal user. It just works. But when I test the installer and application on another computer (also running Windows 7 as a local administrator) I get the following exception:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not
>   allowed.

The exception is thrown by the `RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(string)` method which [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) retrieves a subkey as read-only which I thought should be ok.

I have tried following all the rules and recommendations when it comes to registry accesses on Windows Vista and later, but it seems that I still miss something. What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Requested registry access is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562350/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed)

Comment: I saw that question before posting, but I don't think it is a duplicate. That was about **writing** to parts of registry, this is about **reading** (which should be ok without administrator or elevated privileges). Sure, maybe a manifest might "solve" the problem, but I don't want to require administrator privileges.

Comment: What registry key are you trying to access?  Can you read it with regedit?  What permissions does it have?

Comment: Question was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741599/unable-to-read-registry-system-security-securityexception-requested-registry-a