# c# - How can i get access in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software

Tags: c#

i try to add a key in registry key \local machine 
But i got this error: **Requested registry access is not allowed.**

changed linker -> manifest file -> UAC Execution Level to requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator'),

but again the same error.

Comment: Do you have this error, if you do "run as administrator"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requested registry access is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562350/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the correct definition in your app.manifest? It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication" />
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <security>
         <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
         </requestedPrivileges>
      </security>
   </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

And make sure that you get the UAC admin prompt beforehand.